# AAPT: error: resource drawable/edittext_search_donation_request not found

Tags: android, android-drawable

> Android resource linking failed
>   C:\Users\Islam\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBloodyApp\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:74:5-78:13: AAPT: error: resource drawable/edittext_search_donation_request (aka com.example.mybloodyapp:drawable/edittext_search_donation_request) not found.

[image]

[image]